# Jquery: iphone style checkbox plugin, why is it so big? can't it be so much simplier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, checkbox

I was looking up jquery checkbox scripts/plugins, and I came across this one: [Jquery Checkbox Plugin](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html)

Why is it 8kb? that's absolutely HUGE for something that could be so incredibly simple, right? I'm not that good at Javascript/Jquery, but I know that you can set up a click event on an image that toggles a checkbox that has the same class, or something to that effect. So if it could be so simple, why is it so big?

I've seen 30+KB tooltip plugins, that's RIDICULOUS and HORRIBLE, you could accomplish the same thing for much less... why do people do this?

Comment: This sounds like a rant to me. Write a comparable plugin that's smaller. Then use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8kb is a lot, [here's one](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-checkbox/) that's 2kb instead.